# Excal macro loop for each element in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I've got a relatively big amount of data which I want to put in graphs.

Basically, what I have is multiple components (in total 30-ish but in the example below I'll limit the code to 5 components), and each component has one column.
I've assigned the column numbers to the respective components, declared as integers.
Sometimes I don't want a component to have a graph so that's where there's a gap in the numbers (e.g. in between diat and hydr is another component in column 5 but for this one there shouldn't be a graph).

Then I wanted to put all the components of which I want a graph into one array and do a For... Next loop so a graph would be automatically created for each element in the array (so for each component in the array).

Obviously I did something wrong :-). The code gets stuck on the first time I try to refer to the respected element in the array: ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Cells(9, **componentlist(1, i)**)

```
Dim diat, hydr, para, terb, theo As Integer
diat = 4        'column number of the component named diat
hydr = 6        'column number of the component named hydr
para = 7        'column number of the component named para
terb = 9        'column number of the component named terb
theo = 10       'column number of the component named theo

Dim componentlist As Variant
componentlist = Array(diat, hydr, para, terb, theo)

For i = 1 To UBound(componentlist)

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Cells(9, componentlist(1, i))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets(2).Range(Cells(10, 3), Cells(21, 3))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets(2).Range(Cells(10, componentlist(1, i)), Cells(21, componentlist(1, i)))

Next
```

My experience with VBA is limited so does anyone of you know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array()` creates a single-dimension array with lower bound of zero (unless you're using `Option Base 1` at the top of your module).

So you should loop from 0 to `ubound(componentlist)-1` and you only need to use `componentlist(i)` since your array only has one dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should investigate is whether LBOUND(componentlist) is 1 or 0 and fix the **for** loop if necessary.

The next thing to fix is the dimensionality of **componentlist** .  It should be single-dimensioned.